# RewriteRule redirect all to index.php when folder exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

In my server I have this

1. .htaccess

   ```
   ErrorDocument 403 index.php
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rec=$1 [L,QSA]
   ```
2. index.php
3. folder1

   ```
   .htaccess='deny for all'
   ```
4. folder2

   ```
   .htaccess='deny for all'
   ```
5. folder3

   ```
   .htaccess=''
   ```
6. folder4

   ```
   .htaccess=''
   ```

I want to redirect all to index.php, it work well for all, but when I try this on existing folders where no .htaccess, without slash, like this:

> domain.com/folder3
> domain.com/folder4

it redirect to

> domain.com/folder3 -------> domain.com/folder3/?rec=folder3
>   domain.com/folder4 -------> domain.com/folder4/?rec=folder4

but I whant to this

> domain.com/folder1 -------> domain.com/folder1/ .......ok
>   domain.com/folder2 -------> domain.com/folder2/ .......ok
>   domain.com/folder3 -------> domain.com/folder3/ .......Not work, domain.com/folder3/?rec=folder3
>   domain.com/folder4 -------> domain.com/folder4/ .......Not work, domain.com/folder4/?rec=folder4
>   
>   domain.com/folder1/ -------> domain.com/folder1/ .......ok
>   domain.com/folder2/ -------> domain.com/folder2/ .......ok
>   domain.com/folder3/ -------> domain.com/folder3/ .......ok
>   domain.com/folder4/ -------> domain.com/folder4/ .......ok

the question is this:
why if the folder haven't "deny from all" it will redirect differ when I link him without slash, and how to solve the problem, that anything will be redirected to index.php on root folder.

Comment: Could you try changing it to: RewriteRule ^(.)/?$ index.php?rec=$1 ?

Comment: Its better to have one single .htaccess file on the root to handle other folders; keeping track of .htaccess files can be hard if you're making ton of changes.

Comment: I tried it in server and it worked OK, but in localhost not!